# CoreData -- many-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many

I have two entities in `CoreData` -- Doctors and Patients. Each patient can have several Doctors, and each Doctor can have several Patients (i.e. many-to-many relationship).

That's all easy. Now the juicy bit -- I want to track the times of **all** visits of Patients to Doctors.

In other words, I need to know that `Patient A` visited `Doctor X` at `time 1` **and** `Patient A` visited `Doctor Y` at `time 2`.

How can this be done?

---

I thought about adding an NSDictionary property to `Patient` entity, where `value` would be Doctor's `objectID` and `key` would be `NSDate` time of visit, but it doesn't look like a good approach.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an entity to hold the visit details.  You could have an entity with PatientID, DoctorID, and visit details.

With the two entities you have, you will only be able to store details of a single visit